# Autofill clear background trick stopped working?

Tags: html, css

I had this piece of CSS implemented to have a transparent autofill background. But something has recently changed that it stopped working?

```
@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
    to {
        color: white;
        background: transparent;

    }
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Is there a fix to this?

[image: Remove white background]

```css
  form {
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  margin: 15px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

textarea,
select,
input {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

textarea {
  height: 200px;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

textarea+label {
  width: calc(100% - 2px) !important;
  top: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

textarea:invalid,
select:invalid,
input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
  color: red;
}

textarea:invalid+label,
select:invalid+label,
input:invalid+label {
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 360px;
  color: red;
}

textarea:focus+label,
select:focus+label,
input:focus+label,
label {
  position: absolute;
  background: #a4a290;
  max-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  height: 28px;
  font: 14px/28px sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  color: red;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

textarea:focus+label {
  height: 0;
  color: red;
  @-webkit-keyframes autofill {
    to {
      color: white;
      background: transparent;
    }
  }
  input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" required/>
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="secondname" required/>
    <label for="secondname">Second Name</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="type" required>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">Type 1</option>
      <option value="2">Type 2</option>
      <option value="3">Type 3</option>
      <option value="4">Type 4</option>
    </select>
    <label for="type">Select type...</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="comment" required/></textarea>
    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Please proivde [MCVE]

Comment: Is this browser specific?

Comment: Added the minimal example. Not sure if it's browser specific, just want it to work on chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just this would do the job perfectly :

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```css
form {
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  margin: 15px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

textarea,
select,
input {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

textarea {
  height: 200px;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}

textarea+label {
  width: calc(100% - 2px) !important;
  top: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

textarea:invalid,
select:invalid,
input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
  color: red;
}

textarea:invalid+label,
select:invalid+label,
input:invalid+label {
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 360px;
  color: red;
}

textarea:focus+label,
select:focus+label,
input:focus+label,
label {
  position: absolute;
  background: #a4a290;
  max-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  height: 28px;
  font: 14px/28px sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  color: red;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

textarea:focus+label {
  height: 0;
  color: red;
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" required />
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="email" id="email" required />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="secondname" required />
    <label for="secondname">Second Name</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="type" required>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">Type 1</option>
      <option value="2">Type 2</option>
      <option value="3">Type 3</option>
      <option value="4">Type 4</option>
    </select>
    <label for="type">Select type...</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="comment" required /></textarea>
    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

<sup>[Source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/)</sup>

Comment: Finally!!! Thank you, I feel like I had this code somewhere but manage to delete it somehow and that's why id did not work anymore!

Answer (score 1):

https://jsbin.com/zofuqunavo/

```
@keyframes autofill {
    to {
        color: white;
        background: green;
    }
}

input:focus {
    animation-name: autofill;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Using `input:focus` selector instead of `input:autofill` seem fix your issue.

Autofill is a bit unstable feature, the behaviour is changed multiple times and each browser has own implementation.

Comment: I am still getting the issue, now the green flashes for a brief second. After that I keep getting the white background again. Like in the image above.